# Entity Framework Core self referencing and inheritance

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-core, relationship

I am working on a EF Core model like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRKbt.png)

You can see that there are both one-to-many and one many-to-many relation here.
I was thinking that I could create a base class and have all the entities in the image inherit from that.
And I was thinking that I could have a self-reference in the base class as well.

What I try to do is model is a node tree structure and the nodes are of different types. There is actually an end node, but I thought I could make it sort of more open ended.

I don`t know if this sounds clear to you. But I try to describe this a s good as I can.

All help is of course appriciated